# How to add padding to Ivory Search on Wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I'm looking for some CSS to add to my site which will allow me to add padding to an instance of an Ivory Search block.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS but you can change the value according to your needs!

```
.is-form-style input.is-search-input {
    padding: 25px;
}
.is-form-style button.is-search-submit {
    height: 52px;
}
.is-form-style button.is-search-submit .is-search-icon {
    height: 52px;
    padding-top: 15px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It's working with the only exception being padding for the search button. I've tried padding top and bottom in .is-form-style button.is-search-submit .is-search-icon {